# how to use entiy mapping this data (like json but not )

Tags: json, spring-boot

I have a problem recently.
springboot receive request, but strange!
how to use entity mapping this data below
This strange data:
[image]

```
a=
    {
        b=
           {
             b1=null,
             b2=1,
             b3=null,
             b4=null,
             b5=null
        },
        c={
             c1=null,
             c2=1,
             c3=nfsaf
        },
        ds=
        [
            {
             d1=dsdsadad,
             d2=null,
             d3=null
        },
        {...} 
        ]
    }
```

I try use jackson or gson to convert it,but error.
If there is no good way,i finally use regular expression to catch!
that`s all,Ignore these,Ignore these,Ignore these,Ignore these
very grateful to you for your help!

Comment: If your application will receive a non formal data format, in this case you should write your own parser to parse it and convert it to your internal representation aka java beans.

Comment: yea,i just use HandlerMethodArgumentResolver to parse this data,this data is so Not common,3ks